# TestCafe - How to increase maximum wait time for an If Statement or explicitly defined timeout for If Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to write tow If Statements in which, if the conditions are coming alternately then my code is working fine.

But when both Statements are true together then the second If Statement always skipped because there is a time difference of 5-6 seconds after the first condition executed.

So even though second condition is valid ( waiting for a window to appear) it never went inside the second if-Statement.

I tried writing timeout but it didn't work in TestCafe.

Someone please help if there is any inbuild function to be use for If-Condition just like it is there for assertion -

// await t.expect('.boarding-pass', { timeout: 10000 });

Similar option is not working under If Condition -
// if ( '.boarding-pass'.exists, { timeout: 10000 }){ do something}

It is working only if the Boarding Pass Screen is appearing, if not then it is waiting for 10 seconds and skip second If Statement.

I am not putting the codes for now. If you really need real codes to resolve my issue then I will try to recreate it using some public application.

Comment: Please format your question so it's not one block of text mixed up with code. It's hard to read, so people might choose to close your question after the first sentence, which reduces your changes of getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited hope this will be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [Wait Mechanism for Selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/built-in-wait-mechanisms.html#wait-mechanism-for-selectors) to conditionally execute test statements.

For example, the following code waits for two elements to appear in DOM (you can specify the [timeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/constructor.html#optionstimeout) option), and if an element exists and is visible, clicks it.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture('Selector')
    .page('http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example');

test ('test1',async (t)=\> {
    const selector1 = Selector('#remote-testing');
    const selector2 = Selector('#remote-testing-wrong', { timeout: 10000 } ); //wrong id, it will never appear

    const element1 = await selector1();
    const element2 = await selector2();

    if(element1 && element1.visible) {
        await t.click(selector1);
    }

    if(element2 && element2.visible) {
        await t.click(selector2);
    }
});
```

Please note, that you should use this approach only if the page contains elements that appear occasionally and unpredictably (like a chat window from a third-party component), and you can't turn them off in a test. If an element always appears on executing the test scenario, the recommended way is to use built-in wait mechanisms for actions like click, typetext, etc

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This option already tried before asking this question but didn't work. Only difference you suggested is to add 2 conditions "element2 && element2.visible" I was checking only element2.visible. But both option didn't work for me. I also tried adding await but that is even worst because it is making the condition always true and even though page doesn't exist it is going inside IF Statement. Maybe this solution not for TestCafe.

Comment: It this case, I need a working example to reproduce the issue and find an appropriate solution.